# $route.reload() not fetching updated data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angular JS and i am facing an issue.
I have a HTML page , where there are two groups A & B and under each group i have 4 people name each.

I am trying to move a person from B to A. Its getting updated in DB but after i click the move button the page is not getting refreshed so that we can see the moved person name in A.

How can i make it rebind data.

I tried $route.reload();

But it didn't work. Can anyone explain why ?

Thanks

Arjun Menon

Comment: No we can't without the code.

Comment: hi, code means??? you want the script part?

Comment: Your code is not working. And you want us to find out why. How would that be possible if we don't know antything about the code that is not working (apart from that it's not working). You should post an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** or better yet create a reproducing fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: the route.reload() should do the trick of rebinding data right?? or am i missing something?

 if ($rootScope.skillupdate.length > 0) {
                angular.forEach($rootScope.skillupdate, function (selectedSkill) {
                    MoveSkillToCategory(selectedSkill);
                });
                $rootScope.SkillCheckvisbile = false;
                $rootScope.skillupdate = null;
                $route.reload();                               
            }

Comment: It depends onn where/how/when is the data bound. It will not update the whole app (it's not a refresh, like hitting F5). It will reload the current **view**.

Comment: ok thanks.. i thought it will rebind the data

Comment: Like I said, it **does** rebind the data that are related to the view/route. Not the whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$route.reload()` will reload the view (associated with the current route), re-initialize the controllers (of the view, not the whole app) etc.

It will **not** reload the whole application (only the parts that are associated witht the current view/route).

Comment: Hi, the problem is the data shown in this page is fetched from another view. So that's why the data is not fetched.So i must find a way to invoke that page refresh i guess...

Comment: Is it possible to provide a route in $route.reload()

Comment: What do you mean ? `$route.reload()` reloads the current route. What would the provided argument do ? (Why don't you create an SSCCE or plunkr/fiddle ? It will be easier for us and you will get a more accurate answer to your problem :))

Comment: as i said , the data for the view that holds the A & B group in the page is bound from another route. When my website is run, when it shows the main page , these data are taken and bound to $rootscope.Employee. THen when i click the menu say Employee details the current view data is fetched from this $rootscope.Employee. So the scope get modiefied only when the route is that of home page. But since i am in employee route, the changed data wont reflect in the current page.

Comment: Sounds like your app's design in flawed. What if someone lands on the Employees page directly (without passing by the homepage first) ? You need to load the data differently.

Comment: There is login page. So it wil land to HomePage even if the URL is of employee page

Comment: @user3851706: What if they are already logged in ? Besides you disable deep linking which is a useful and important feature of any webapp (and one that is given to you for free with AngularJS). In any case, even the fact that you run into difficulties with such a simple task (i.e. navigating to a route), is a clear sign you are doing something wrong !

Comment: The problem, i can't change the concept here. When we login in the details of all employees are set in $rootScope.Employee and it is used in EmployeeDetails page. So I am helpless here. Since there is two way binding i was able to handle my situation where i changed the old value in scope with new value on success of async call.  Anyway thanks a lot Expert System

Comment: @user3851706: NP :) Please, consider accepting the answer, since it answers the original question.